# What is a good debug front end plugin

Tags: filetype-python, plugin-python-mode

I would like to use vim to write python codes, it is good to use python-mode plugin. However, I have to debug with pdb in the terminal, which is quite inconvenient since I have no way to view the whole code. Are there any plugins that can be the front end of debug tools such as gdb or pdb, and allow me to debug in vim directly?

Comment: Probably off topic here, but perhaps investigate the tui switch in gdb, which indeed lets you "view the whole code".

Comment: @DrEval Yes, I know, and there is a tool named cgdb which is even better, but how about python/pdb? From what I know, it has neither tui nor a tool named cpdb or so.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the existing plugins with [Vim Awesome](https://vimawesome.com/?q=pdb):

> Vim Awesome is a directory of Vim plugins sourced from GitHub,
>   Vim.org, and user submissions. Plugin usage data is extracted from
>   dotfiles repos on GitHub.

A quick search on that site brought these results:

- vimpdb by Godefroid Chapelle - Pdb and Vim integration
- pdbvim by Mathew Yeates - Interface to pdb for debugging python scripts
- pybreak by Niklas Thörne - Vim function for toggling pdb.set_trace statement at cursor position